# XML Cdata format and variable input TSQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, cdata

```
DECLARE @TransactionId NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @TransactionDateTime DATETIME
--Setting Variable
SET @TransactionId= (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, CURRENT_TRANSACTION_ID()))
SET @TransactionDateTime= GETDATE()
--Start the XML Selction
SELECT
1 AS Tag,
NULL AS Parent,
NULL AS 'Tag!1!',
NULL AS 'TransactionType!2!CollectSampling!cdata',
NULL AS 'TransactionID!2!TransactionId!cdata',
NULL AS 'TransactionDateTime!2!TransactionDateTime!cdata',
NULL AS 'ContainerName!2!Name!cdata',
NULL AS 'Make!2!Make!cdata',
NULL AS 'Model!2!Model!cdata',
NULL AS 'Price!2!Price!cdata',
NULL AS  'Type!2!Type!cdata'
Union  ALL
SELECT
2 AS Tag,
1 AS Parent,
NULL,
'CollectSample',
@TransactionId,
@TransactionDateTime,
[Name] ,
[Make] ,
[Model] ,
[Price]  ,
[Type]
from dbo.RepCar
FOR XML EXPLICIT,  ROOT('Message')
```

The below is the output I would like to have but keep getting XML formats errors. Also just the Message is the parent
Would like output as below.I'm using variables to populate a couple of tags and CollectSample is static field.

```
 <Message>
    <TransactionType><![CDATA[CollectSamplingData]]></TransactionType>
    <TransactionID><![CDATA[0CA4E46F-5143-498C-B1AC-F990FF70462E]]></TransactionID>
    <TransactionDate><![CDATA[2020-01-10T14:20:30-05:00]]></TransactionDate>
    <CName><![CDATA[Name]]></CName>
    <MakeCar><![CDATA[Make]]></MakeCar>
    <MakeModel><![CDATA[Model]]></MakeModel>
    <DataValue><![CDATA[Price]]></DataValue>
    <MakeType><![CDATA[Type]]></MakeType>
  </Message>
```

Comment: Gatorsdog, you are using somewhat outdated **FOR XML EXPLICIT** approach. Please modify your original post and add missing DDL  and data sample population for the dbo.repcar DB table.

Comment: Gatorsdog, there are good reasons why SQL-Server's developers decided not to support `CDATA` sections. Even more, if you store the XML above into a native XML data type, any `CDATA` section will disappear. This format was introduced to embed unescaped content so the engine should be fine with *reading* it, but - in general - there is no reason to *write* XML with `CDATA` sections. Do you really, really need this old-fashioned approach? The `EXPLICIT` mode is a real headache...

Comment: Unfortunately Yes. I'm working with a vendor and they requested the format . Trust me I sent the XML and they sent back the need for CDATA.

Comment: @Gatorsdog you might use simple `concat()` an create this on string level. But never try to *store* this xml in native xml type...

Comment: USE tempdb
CREATE TABLE RepCar (

 ContainerName     VARCHAR(10),
 Make              VARCHAR(10),
 Model             VARCHAR(10),
 Price             INT,
 Type              VARCHAR(10)
 )


 

insert into RepCar
select 'M1', 'BMW', '750' , 75000, 'Sedan' union all
select 'M2', 'Lexus', 'GSF' , 85000, 'Sedan'union all
select 'M3', 'Lexus', 'IS', 35000, 'Sport'union all
select 'M4', 'BMW', 'M4', 105000, 'Sport'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @RepCar table
(
[Name] varchar(10),
[Make] varchar(10),
[Model] varchar(10),
[Price]  money,
[Type] varchar(10)
);

insert into @RepCar
(
Name, Make, Model, Price, Type
)
values
('Car1', 'Make1', 'Model1', 100, 'Type1'),
('Car2', 'Make2', 'Model2', 200, 'Type2'),
('Car3', 'Make3', 'Model3', 300, 'Type3');



DECLARE @TransactionId NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @TransactionDateTime DATETIME
--Setting Variable
SET @TransactionId= (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, CURRENT_TRANSACTION_ID()))
SET @TransactionDateTime= GETDATE()
--Start the XML Selction


/*
ElementName!TagNumber!AttributeName!Directive 

AttributeName
Provides the name of the attribute to construct in the specified ElementName. This is the behavior if Directive is not specified.

!!!! If Directive is specified and it is xml, cdata, or element, this value is used to construct an element child of ElementName, and the column value is added to it.!!!!

*/


select 1 AS Tag,
0 AS Parent,
'CollectSamplingData' as 'Message!1!TransactionType!cdata',
@TransactionId as 'Message!1!TransactionID!cdata',
@TransactionDateTime  as 'Message!1!TransactionDate!cdata',
[Name]  as 'Message!1!CName!cdata',
[Make]  as 'Message!1!MakeCar!cdata',
[Model]  as 'Message!1!MakeModel!cdata',
[Price]   as 'Message!1!DataValue!cdata',
[Type]  as 'Message!1!MakeType!cdata'
from @RepCar --dbo.RepCar
FOR XML EXPLICIT, ROOT('Messages');
```